# How to replace text based on counter value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Call to the count function made by two group of checkboxes. First group represents categories, when clicked subjects for that category will be listed out.

html: id: counter displays count value. id: select replaces text acordingly

```
<div class="small-8 text-left columns" style="left:-30px;">

  <span id="counter"><span id="count">0</span></span>

  <span id="select">Select Subjects</span>

</div>
```

script:(categories group) To pass value for the subjects to be fetched by ajax.  `updateCount();is the count function call.`

```
$("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]").change(function() {  
  var selectedval = $(this).val();
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
    sendtobox(selectedval, $("#slider1").val(),"regis");
  } else {
    $("th."+selectedval).remove();
    updateCount();

  }
});
```

(subjects group)

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^=sub][type=checkbox]', updateCount);
```

count function:

```
function updateCount () {

 $('#count').text($('[id^=sub][type=checkbox]:checked').length);

}
```

script to replace text:

```
$(".close-reveal-modal").on("click",function()
{
    document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = "Select subject";
    var str = document.getElementById("select").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("Select subject", "Selected Subject");
    document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = res;
});
```

Now I can replace text and the count works just fine! My problem is it doesn't obey the English grammar!

If 0 item/subjects returned, the text should be 0 Selected Subjects and if more than 1 is checked, it should say the same. See the (s) must be added in 'subject' word.

My problem is , I couldn't identify number of counts to replace this text.

I want someting like this:

```
if ($("#count") >1 || ($("#count")==0))

      {
        var res = str.replace("Select subject", "**Selected Subjects"**);
        document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = res;

      }
     else
      {
     var res = str.replace("Select subject", "**Selected Subject"**);
        document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = res;
}
```

I tried to alert $('#count').length , it red like this each  time the checkbox checked:

1 1 1 1

What I'm expecting is

1 -when clicked once

2 - when clicked twice

This way would be easier for me to replace text indeed!

Comment: Please don't tag PHP when your question has nothing to with it.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want the TEXT of the span with id 'count' for that comparison:

```
if ($("#count").text() == "1") {
    // singular
}
else {
    // plural
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot..Thats what I wanted